# How do I store a binary file in an sql database?

Tags: java, sql

I have a varbinary column we use to store excel files. I need to update this column with the contents of a different xls file that is currently on my filesystem.

Given a java.sql.Connection, how should I update the row?

We are using sql server 2005.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up doing the following:

```
PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement("update MyTable set binaryData = ? where id= 9");
st.setBinaryStream(1, new FileInputStream(file), (int)file.length());
st.execute();
```

Comment: Warning: if your file is longer than Integer.MAX_VALUE bytes, casting its length() to an int will give you a negative number, which may cause setBinaryStream not to work properly. I don't know why setBinaryStream wasn't declared to take a "long" as the length.

Answer (score 2):

Using a java.util.Connection and the correct SQL you could create an appropriate java.sql.PreparedStatement (I don't use SQL Server, so you'd be better writing the SQL yourself).

You can create a java.sql.Blob using the byte data read from your xls file.

Call .setBlob(Blob) on your PreparedStatement and then execute it.

I didn't write the code for you, but that should be the basics.

Answer (score 0):

Pass in a byte array to a [BLOB](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/jdbc/blob.html) field.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @TanmayPatil This is not a link-only answer.  It concisely explains what you should do. Step 1: get a byte array.  Step 2: put it into a BLOB field.  What am I missing?  Other resources can provide details if you really need that much hand-holding.

Answer (score -2):

In older versions of Java you might try

```
obj.setObject("@somefield", some_data);
```

Comment: I posted this to help someone who might be forced to use very old Java, I am not advocating this as a modern solution.